# What is the Scope of Bean object with BeanUtils.populate() Method?

Tags: jsp, servlets, apache-commons-beanutils

i previously used `<jsp:useBean>` tags that have facility to decide the scope of bean for `page or request or session or application` but now i moved to MVC architechture, where i am using `BeanUtils` class to set the property of bean in `Servlets`. Please tell me what is the default `SCOPE` is provided by this method? and what i have to do if i want to change the scope??
 I am using syntax:

`BeanUtils.populate(bean, request.getParameterMap());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BeanUtils#popuate()` doesn't store the bean anywhere. It just populates the bean. The changes are reflected in the `bean` instance which you've there. You know, Java is Object Oriented and pass-by-value. After that line is called, the bean is populated. You just need to store the bean in the desired scope yourself.

Request scope:

```
request.setAttribute("bean", bean);
```

Session scope:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("bean", bean);
```

Application scope:

```
getServletContext().setAttribute("bean", bean);
```

Either way, it's available in JSP by `${bean}`. There's no page scope, but that's not relevant anyway.

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Answer (score 0):

There is no scope associated with javabeans. The scope is only jsp/webapp related. In that sense, BeanUtils.populate(..) does not store the bean anywhere in the web contexts, and so it doesn't have a scope. If you choose to add the thus created bean to a given context, only then it would have scope.